# Angular Material Component Custom Attributes

Tags: angular, components

I have created a component whose sole purpose is to display the color palette hues for a given palette (primary, secondary, accent, emphasis, warn)

I want to allow the component to be added to any page using the component template (my-color-palette-component) and color attribute (primary, secondary, accent, etc) specified as:

```
<my-color-palette-component color="primary"></my-color-palette-component>
```

How can I retrieve the value of the color attribute and insert it into my component.html as the class attribute?

Example, in my my-color-palette-component.component.html code:

```
<div class={{this.color?}}>
  ...markup
</div>
```

So that the DOM markup becomes:

```
<div class="primary">...markup</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you have to declare the variable `color` in your component and mark it as an [input](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#inputs-outputs)(if you haven't done so yet):

```
@Input() public color:string; //Remove the typings in case you're not using typescript
```

After that you can simply set the class attribute like this:

```
<div [class]="color">...markup</div>
```

One thing to note is that this will completely [override a class attribute](https://angular.io/guide/template-syntax#class-binding) you directly set in your template:

```
<div class="someOtherClass" [class]="color">...markup</div>
```

Assuming that `color` has the value `primary` this would result in the following:

```
<div class="primary">...</div>
```

In a case like this you can use [ngClass](https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass):

```
<div class="someOtherClass" [ngClass]="color">...markup</div>
```

Comment: That was easy! Thanks for the help. If you have a suggestion for a good tutorial series on developing components, please share.

Comment: angular.io itself has pretty good guides. This part right here might be of interest to you: https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction